# How can I exclude Materialised Views from a pg_dump

Tags: postgresql, materialized-view, pg-dump, postgresql-12

I'm doing a pg_dump of an AWS RDS database so I can use it for local development, but there are some large tables I want to exclude. I've successfully removed them using the `--exclude-table=blah*` flag on `pg_dump`, but when I try to build a db from the dump it fails because there are some Materialised views that use the tables I've excluded.

So my question is - how do I exclude materialised views from the db dump?

Comment: have you tried --exclude-table=view1?

Comment: Can you have multiple `--exclude table`s?

Comment: I think you are looking for `--exclude-table-data` option, not `--exclude-table`. With this option, the dump will contain the table structure (and therefore matview will be created), but not the contents of those tables.

Comment: @KathyRindhoops you you can have multiole exclude views or tables. but you must define for every table/view its own exclude

Comment: Thanks, I will try this and update